# power on problem in lumia 800

Tags: nokia-lumia-800

I have a nokia lumia 800 and it would not come on. The last 5 hours I have been trying to get the phone to come on but it's not charging. Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem? I love the phone and would really like to get it working again.plz help me.

Comment: Can you add the steps you have taken to attempt to turn on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

If there is sufficient charge in the battery to run it, the 3 finger force reboot should start it. Hold down the power button, camera button, & volumn down all at the same time for about 10 seconds and you should feel the haptic vibe that it is powering up. Let go of all buttons when you feel that vibe and is will boot up.